# Reading line in PDF using python

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, pdf, pypdf, pdf-parsing

I am trying write a program which give trace matrix for a requirement -code- Test

for which i am not able to read the requirement tags from PDF line by line from PDF.

Below is the program i tried.

```
import os, sys, time
import sys
import glob
import xlwt
sys.path.insert(0,'C:/Python27/xlwt-0.7.5')
import pyPdf
from StringIO import StringIO
import docx

req_path_py = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) +"\\Requirement\\"
req_list = glob.glob("%s/*.pdf" %req_path_py)

def getPDFContent(path):
    content = ""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
    # Iterate pages
    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    # Collapse whitespace
    content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
    return content
def topReq():
    global req_path_py, req_list
    with open("traceMetrix.txt","w") as txt:
        txt.write("CSD ID \tSRD ID \tSDD ID\tCODE ID\tTEST ID\n")
        pdfContent = StringIO(getPDFContent(req_list[0]).encode("ascii", "ignore"))
        for line in pdfContent:
            if '{CSD' in line:
                txt.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    topReq()
```

Content of PDF looks like below

```
Trace:
{CSD-PROS-PLN-001}
Abc shall do abc
Trace:
{CSD-PROS-PLN-002}
Abc shall do abc
Trace:
{CSD-PROS-PLN-003}
Abc shall do abc
```

Also sometimes some content will be inside table sy below entry is inside a table

```
Trace:
{CSD-PROS-PLN-003}
Abc shall do abc
```

The purpose of such search is say, i get top level req as "{CSD-PROS-PLN-003}" then i will search other pdf / code/test for the derived requirement / implementation / test from this requirement.

Thanks